# RV042. Public IP on LAN port. Is it possible?

Tags: networking, ip, router

I have a RV042 router with a public static IP (XXX.XXX.XXX.42) and 4 LAN ports assigned to net 192.168.1.0/24.

Can I connect a host to one of the LAN ports and assign it a public static IP (XXX.XXX.XXX.43) which I own? How can I do that?

One of the LAN ports is connected to a switch, with patch chords in the middle and a lot of cables. If there's a way of doing that without moving cables it would be even better.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Unless your ISP has allocated you additional IP addresses, you don't. If they have allocated you additional IPs, then choose an address to be your gateway, assign it to the inside interface of your router, and then assign the rest of the addresses to your LAN-side clients.

Comment: You could place the `xx.xx.xx.43` system in a DMZ, which I believe the RV042 supports.

Comment: It is possible to configure a network like that, I have at one time done so on a router running Ubuntu 10.04. Whether your particular router support it, I don't know.

Comment: Downvote. This is basic networking knowledge and does note belong here.

Comment: @Daniel RV042 is not a home router and I don't consider knowing how to configure it a "basic network knowledge". The router is installed in an enterprise and I'm asking the question as part of my job and not a hobby. Considering this, is my question still off-topic? If so, I'm sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually want is a One-To-One NAT. This allows the router to translate an incoming public address with a private IP within your network.

[These](http://sbkb.cisco.com/CiscoSB/GetArticle.aspx?docid=9c994cc0865c446489cde9aeaf990c49_One_to_One_NAT_on_a_RV042.xml&pid=2&converted=0) instructions provide detailed instructions, but the jist of it is to enable One-To-One NAT, give the external and internal IP, and set the range length to "1". When done, you should be able to access your internal device using the external IP address. This *might* not work if this router isn't capable of hairpin-NAT, so test it externally too.

Comment: your solution worked like a charm. I was trying to avoid using NAT, but at the same time I didn't want to move cables (which, now that I think about it in greater depth is probably impossible unless you can assign two different IP's for the same LAN port. Are there any routers that can do that?). @thelogix solution seemed a very good one also, but would have required to do some cable work (to connect the host to the DMZ/Internet port on the RV042), so I preferred to go with the no-cable-work one.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Moderator asked me for a more verbose answer. Heres the rephrased one:

I suggest you make a DMZ, with a public IP pointed to a single host internally.

Have a look in your local router documentation, to see how this is accomplished, as it varies from each brand and I'm unfamiliar with Cisco SOHO routers.

For reference, heres a link to the documentation for your router, on how to do this:
[Cisco's official documentation](http://sbkb.cisco.com/CiscoSB/GetArticle.aspx?docid=40e48a8df0474ee1bf293ce132583f4d_Configuration_of_Multiple_Public_IP_on_De_Militarized_Zone.xml&pid=2&converted=0) has a step by step guide on how to add a DMZ with a public ip pointed to a single host internally.

Comment: You could also use NAT or port-forwarding if you don't want to expose the whole machine to the internet, or still maintain the ability to connect to that machine on your local network.

Comment: @Bert, thanks for the suggestion, but I'm trying to avoid NAT for now because what I'm trying to do was requested by an external company that provides us with a device, they are highly ignorant about networking and insisted in using a public IP for the device. So I'm just avoiding more futile discussions with them and trying to give them what they want. Exposing their device to the internet is not a worry for me. I'll just let them deal with the inconveniences of their own simplistic approach.

Comment: @thelogix, your solution seems like a very good one, but I didn't try it and tried nathan-c instead (I've explained why in a comment on that solution). However, I've learned one or two tricks from the provided link, so thank you very much!